# Reverse osmosis Water desalination

Tags: experimental-physics, osmosis

Is it feasible to submerge a reverse osmosis system in the sea in order to use the increasing pressure to push through the membrane and as the salt was removed would the lighter water rise on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the efficiency of the RO membrane. When the membrane conversion rate was below 20 percent, the answer in general would be yes. However, with the newer type membranes the conversion rates are quite high.

In RO sea water desalinization, the normal pressure required to force the the pure water molecules through the membrane is in the range of 800 to 1,000 psi so the system must be over 2,200 feet below surface level. The pure water (Flux) as it is collected is at a much lower pressure so you will need to pump it back to the surface. If you don't, the pressure head will equalize on both sides of the membrane and the flux will end. Where savings may enter the process is that the pure water flow rate to pump will be much less than the initial flow entering the system. Of course there are many other factors to consider. Plant size etc all Play a role. An example is as follows:

If the RO system is to produce 1,000,000 gallon of pure water in an 8 hour day, and the RO membranes has a 30 percent conversion rate, then the total flow required to enter the system is:

```
 Total flow = 1,000,000/0.30 = 3,300,000  or 3,300,000 gallons/8-hours 
              or, 926 gpm at 1,000-psi pressure.
```

To determine the savings calculate the cost to pump 926 gpm at 1,000-psi vs. 30 percent of that flow at 1,000-psi.